# Searching for Tor hidden servicces

Tags: onion-services, directory, darknet

What resources are best for search .onion networks within the Tor? Unlike the web where you can search for a domain or portal, what equivalent systems are available for search for Tor specific networks basically .onion networks/sites without actually knowing their address? Must you know what they are already to go to them directly or is there a master listing/search/or directory for them? Based on subject or whatnot?

I have read [this questions and the answers](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/661/google-indexing-onion-hidden-sites) but I am looking for a resource or method to look directly within the Tor network layers.

Comment: I don't understand "Must you know what they are already to go to them directly". Without giving an answer... there is no central listing of hidden services.

Comment: I know many of them, hazards of my grey hat status, but I was wondering in general does anyone know of a directory style listing or a search system for it. I know you have to know where they are to get there, that's a given, but specifically wondering if you can search for something topic specific or not. Hope that clarifies my intent for the question.

Answer (score 5):

I think The Hidden Wiki may be what you're looking for:
[Hidden service link](http://kpvz7ki2v5agwt35.onion/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)
[Tor2web link](https://kpvz7ki2v5agwt35.tor2web.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)

Comment: You might be right, thank you. I am going to take a look and see, appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

These are search engines that index .onion sites:

- [Torch](http://xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion/)
- [not Evil](http://hss3uro2hsxfogfq.onion/)
- [Candle](http://gjobqjj7wyczbqie.onion/)
- [ahmia.fi](https://ahmia.fi/search/)

Answer (score 1):

Do you meant by onion search engine? There are some services like TORCH that serves to be Tor search engine. By the way, Onion is a **hidden** service, means no one can find it unless onion owner want to publish their address by putting it into Hidden Wiki or other sites.

Comment: I know onion networks are hidden and you must disclose it to be found, I get that. I am just wondering if there is a directory or search engine that aggregates the available networks and allows their index to be searched to narrow down specific topics of interest. I will give TORCH another look, thanks.

Comment: this isnt true. i started a tor hidden service and never told anyone about it and thousands of people found it and use it.